# Where do you ask hybrid "accounting for programmers" questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm working on an ERP/accounting application and have some questions pertaining to data modeling that are just as much accounting questions as programming ones.

Money.SE does not allow business questions and accounting.SE is in Area 51 and struggling. Further, since my questions deal with how things are stored in a database based on accounting principles and requirements, I really need a person who has both accounting **and** development knowledge.

I've read accounting and bookkeeping books at the library, but most of them talk about how to use your accounting software or how to record journals by hand, not "how to simulate double entry bookkeeping principals in a relational database".

An example question:

> When reconciling an end-of-day credit card settlement, (the process of
>   checking-off individual orders that make up the total in the batch
>   deposit from a merchant account), is the mapping of orders to the
>   settlement done in the accounting journal tables, or in separate meta
>   data tables?
>
> Or in other words, it would seem that for each order placed you would
>   credit the revenue account and the "unsettled funds" asset account
>   (one journal entry per order), and at the end of the day, record a
>   single journal entry moving funds from "unsettled funds" to "bank
>   account", because that is what actually happens.
>
> But when the user
>   checks off the orders that are part of the batch, where is that
>   mapping stored? In the order table, mapped to the journal record for the settlement batch,
>   where all orders in a batch point to the same batch ID they were a part
>   of (which would be order meta data)? Or do those settlement mappings
>   actually need recorded in an accounting journal so they appear in financial statements and the general ledger?

Is this "programming enough" for Stack Overflow or is there a better place?

Comment: What you need is database design.

Comment: I don't think this is "programming enough". It's more about accounting theory than actually asking about how to implement something in your database/code.

Comment: Given that any answer would require an in depth knowledge of accounting principles I don't think its a question that fits here.  Do we have an accounting stack exchange?

Comment: This is a combination of database design and something that needs to be determined at a business level as to what best makes sense for you. There a several ways this can be done that will work from both the database design and accounting side.

Comment: There is an accounting stack exchange in area 51 with 30 supporters. It needs more interest to get to beta though, and it's been around for about 6 months now. The problem with accountants, however, is that they are often clueless about database design. They know how to use *their* software and how to do charts manually on accounting paper, but aren't very good at answering data model questions that require accounting knowledge.

Comment: @JoeW: There are also certain things that are mandated by GAP and government authorities (in case of audit), and certain things that are frequently done but not required. If you are building software for a general audience rather than for a certain company, you would also need to make some sane decisions for the end user. eg. A good accounting package for a Mom & Pop shouldn't expect "Mom" to know or learn accounting, it should just have simple forms that say, "enter x here" and then spit out the forms the accountant expects to see.

Comment: @Nick I agree that a lot of what needs to be done will depend on what your target audience is for the application you are developing.